# Global variable in a register

Tags: c, optimization, cpu-registers

Is this possible to tell the compiler to put a certain **global** variable in a register? Thus effectively blocking this register from use everywhere else. I understand this might be difficult because even a simple call to `malloc()` will require spilling it temporarily.

I am thinking about it because I am looking for a way to efficiently implement a secondary stack for sort of VM and naturally it would be great to store the secondary stack pointer in another register.

Comment: It may depend on the compiler, but I think in gcc something like `register int *foo asm ("r12");` in the global scope would work. See [6.44.5.1 Defining Global Register Variables](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.3.0/gcc/Global-Register-Variables.html).

Comment: from the link of @FlávioToribio : `Note that these points only apply to code that is compiled with the definition. The behavior of code that is merely linked in (for example code from libraries) is not affected.`

Comment: Don't use premature optimisations, expecially if they have global implications! Leave optimisations to the compiler. If you encounter preformance issues at max. optimisation settings, profile and optimise **hotspots**.

Comment: I also don't think it's possible to reserve a register for all the code, including libraries. Even if the compiler gave you such an option, you couldn't control what functions in the library do to registers manually.

Comment: @FlávioToribio: You **can** do it, but of course that requires **all** modules have to be compiled appropriately. Including the standard library. Or the ABI must guarantee the register is not clobbered by functions. This normally only makes sense for very special software, e.g. OS kernel or bare-metal embedded. It hardly is reasonable to even think about it for "normal" application code.

Comment: More importantly, this seems like an XY problem.

Comment: @EOF: I don't think there even is an Y problem at all. It's just some premature (and most likely harmful) optimisation approach.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I don't think Flavio means the `register` keyword, but the whole construct with the gcc extension. That in fact allocated the rewgister fort the variable. Of course if other code is not aware of this reservation, you're in trouble.

Comment: I'd say 'probably not'. To do that you would have to allocate something nobody else is allocating. One thing comes to mind, though unlikely feasible: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_debug_register

Answer (score 2):

In theory, this is possible: You could take any register that the calling conventions require to be preserved across function calls, and use that for your global variable.

However, there are some problems with this:

- The effect is, that your functions will have one less register for local variables available. This means, more memory accesses on average.
- Library functions will **not** preserve the registers value, they will save it on the stack as any other non-clobber register, use it as they please, and restore it before they return.
- As such, it is impossible to pass a callback pointer to a library function, and access the register global from the callback. (But this is probably not your problem anyway.)
- If you are implementing a VM stack as a global variable, you are doing something very wrong in the first place. A stack should be thread local by nature, it has no business being global.

Doing things right, keeping the stack pointer as a local variable within the VM emulator is likely to give you the best performance you can get.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible to tell the compiler to put a certain global variable in a register?

Not really. There is the `register` storage class, but this only means that the variable should be "as fast as possible". This keyword is mostly obsolete nowadays, it is from a time when compilers were trash.

> Thus effectively blocking this register from use everywhere else

It's not possible to select a specific register. You will have to use inline assembler for that.

> I am thinking about it because I am looking for a way to efficiently implement a secondary stack for sort of VM and naturally it would be great to store the secondary stack pointer in another register.

Sounds like you need to be writing assembler overall. It is not even possible to set the stack pointer from C. Or if by "stack" you don't mean the program memory, but rather some data type, don't go fiddle with pre-mature optimizations in the first place.